# Why is fractional statistics and non-Abelian common for fractional charges?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, research-level, topological-order, spin-statistics, anyons

1. Why non integer spins obey Fermi statistics?
2. Why is fractional statistics and non-Abelian common for fractional charges?

Answer (score 7):

Both  fractional/non-Abelian statistics and fractional charges
come from the same origin: long-range entanglements.
This is why fractional/non-Abelian statistics common for fractional charges.

One way to realize long-range entanglements
is through the string-net liquid phase of a pure bosonic model.
The ends of strings in string-net liquid are non-local and are topological defects. They can have fractional statistics. The ends of strings can also carry fractional charges/spins due to the same reason: the ends of strings are non-local and are topological defects.

My [recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.1281) explains such a phenomenon in simple terms. See also  [Topological Charge. What is it Physically?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55204/topological-charge-what-is-it-physically)

Answer (score 2):

Half-integer spin particles obey Fermi-Dirac statistics and integer spin fields obey the Bose-Einstein statistics – it's true because of Pauli's [spin-statistics theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-statistics_theorem).

Concerning the second question, I suppose you meant fractional spin, not fractional charges. In the case of 2 spatial dimensions, the trajectory of one particle around another is non-contractible (if we allow to cross the other particle) so even 2 rotations fail to return us to the original state. That's why the wave function may change by more than by the sign: it may pick a general phase (fractional statistics) or it may even be multiplied by some general unitary matrix (non-Abelian statistics). See [Fractional statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_statistics) on Wikipedia.