# Topological vs. non-topological noetherian charges

Tags: symmetry, charge, noethers-theorem, topology, discrete

What (if any) is the relationship between the conserved (non-topological) noetherian charges and [topological charges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_number)? Namely, is there any "generalization" of the [Noether's first theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) that includes topological charges as subcase and it provides some relationship between these two classes of charge?

Comment: I don't think so. Homotopy charges (aka topological charges) are not necessarily based on discrete groups, or are they?

Answer (score 1):

Let there be given a physical system. What charges are Noetherian and what charges are topological often depend on the precise action formulation and field content of the physical system, see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55204/2451) Phys.SE post.  To simplify the discussion, let us assume that the action formulation is fixed,
and below definitions will then refer to this fixed formulation.

A characteristic feature of a topological conservation law (CL) is that it holds off-shell, i.e. independent of the Euler-Lagrange equations. Olver calls such a CL *trivial of the second kind,* cf. Ref. 1.

Many authors require by definition a topological CL to *not* be a Noetherian CL, i.e. not covered by a Noetherian theorem.

Nevertheless, even if there exists a quasi-symmetry (QS) of the action that via Noether theorem leads to a topological CL, the CL is (as mentioned above) trivial, which (under mild assumptions) means that it corresponds to a trivial QS, cf. Ref. 1. (A *trivial QS* means that the QS transformation vanishes on-shell. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24596/2451) Phys.SE post.)

References:

1. P.J. Olver, Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations, 1993.